# Any logs for AWS RDS auto start?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

From AWS documentation [Stopping an Amazon RDS DB Instance Temporarily](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_StopInstance.html):

> You can stop a DB instance for up to seven days. If you do not manually start your DB instance after seven days, your DB instance is automatically started.

But I cannot find any `StartDBInstance` event in `CloudTrail`. Is it because the start action is not from API call?

Is there any log for the RDS auto start? (something like `AutoStartDBInstance`?)

Answer (score 1):

CloudTrail logs actions performed by you, not by the service internally so you won't see the Automatic Start.

An event is published to SNS however, [`RDS-EVENT-0088`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Events.html)